How do you "bump up" data?
I really dont know how to call it but I will try my best to explain it.
Look at this dataset



Name
Sem 1 GPA
Sem 2 GPA
Sem 3 GPA




Carlos
2.2
Nan
Nan


Carlos
Nan
1.86
Nan


Carlos
Nan
Nan
1.97


Andrew
2.3
Nan
Nan


Andrew
Nan
1.99
Nan


Andrew
Nan
Nan
2.05



Now I want to end up like this



Name
Sem 1 GPA
Sem 2 GPA
Sem 3 GPA




Carlos
2.2
1.86
1.97


Andrew
2.3
1.99
2.05



So I tried doing this
df2 = df.groupby('Name').ffill()

to replace the NaN values with the next Valid Value but I lose the name in the dataframe. I want to keep the name column.

Assuming each row has one value for each name, you can groupby and then aggregate with first, which will ignore the NaN values:
df = df.groupby("Name", as_index=False).agg("first")

     Name  Sem 1 GPA  Sem 2 GPA  Sem 3 GPA
0  Andrew        2.3       1.99       2.05
1  Carlos        2.2       1.86       1.97

